# MS Access: eval() returns NULL when accessing .Column(x, y) property

Tags: vba, ms-access, null, listbox, eval

I have a form and to validate it, I am using eval(). Background is, that I have defined rules in an table. These rules contain placeholders. The rule is compiled and then eval() should check wether its true or false.

Part of one rule contains a check on a listbox value. I identified this to be the problem. I could reduce it to the following:

`Application.Forms("frmDMAE").lstHistory.Column(6, Application.Forms("frmDMAE").lstHistory.ListCount - 1)`

returns ie 2,

`eval("Application.Forms(""frmDMAE"").lstHistory.Column(6, Application.Forms(""frmDMAE"").lstHistory.ListCount - 1)")`

returns NULL - but I can not figure out why!?

`eval("Application.Forms(""frmDMAE"").lstHistory.Column(6, 5)")`

returns NULL as well!? Column 6, row 5 definately contains a numeric value.

Also pasting the following into the debug window shows "2" as return value in both cases:

`Application.Forms("frmDMAE").lstHistory(6, Application.Forms("frmDMAE").lstHistory.ListCount - 1)
Application.Forms("frmDMAE").lstHistory.Column(6, 5)`

Any idea anyone??? I don't have a dime anymore.

[EDIT]

Solution of Andre works. Just change the indexes of the .Column property within Eval(). Use .Column(rowindex, colindex) instead of .Column(colindex, rowindex)!

[/EDIT]

Thank You very much,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. What a strange thing.

Apparently you have to **switch the parameters** (or array indexes) of the `.Column` property around when using it with `Eval()`.

My listbox has 2 rows and 7 columns, with a number in the 6th column (= column 5).

```
? Forms!myForm!myList.Column(5,1)
3600

? Eval("Forms!myForm!myList.Column(5,1)")
Null

? Eval("Forms!myForm!myList.Column(1,5)")
3600
```

I don't really know what to make of this.

Note: I'm using Access 2010.

Comment: Your solution works! And yes that's really strange. I would never ever have tried to change the indexes of the `.Column` property within `Eval()`. You discovered this by random? My random thoughts on this were empty :-).

Comment: Kinda random, yes. I started out getting always NULL (as you), then it suddenly started working and it took me a bit to find out what was going on. I think it was when I tried the same column and row number (this obviously will work with and without Eval).